# Does Swift have an equivalent to pdb.set_trace()

Tags: swift, macos, read-eval-print-loop

I have been investigating Swift for the use of scripts. Is there an equivalent to Python's

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

that will drop a running script into the REPL (i.e. LLDB)?

Answer (score 1):

You can send yourself `SIGTRAP`:

```
    kill(getpid(), SIGTRAP)
```

But you might want to do that only if you know you're running under the debugger. [Apple Technical Q&A QA1361: Detecting the Debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1361/_index.html) shows how to write a function that returns true if the process has a debugger attached. The function is in C, but you can call it from Swift (or try to port it to Swift).